# Keyword argument and dict unpacking gives different results

Tags: python, kivy

I'm stumped. Why are the following two pieces of code not behaving identically?

1)

```
for attr in ("size", "pos"):
    self.bind(**{attr: lambda *args: setattr(self.background, attr, self.__getattribute__(attr))})
```

2)

```
self.bind(size=lambda *args: setattr(self.background, "size", self.__getattribute__("size")))
self.bind(pos=lambda *args: setattr(self.background, "pos", self.__getattribute__("pos")))
```

In the first sample, a keyword argument is given directly.
In the other, a keyword argument is given by unpacking a dict.

Is it some strange Kivy quirk or something with **getattribute**?

Answer (score 4):

It's how closures work in Python: your inner function (a lambda in this case) captures a reference to the variable `attr` itself, not its value. If you change `attr` after creating the function, then the value of `attr` used in the functions also changes. Thus both of your lambdas end up referring to the same value of `attr` (the last one seen in the loop, `"pos"`).

To rectify this, you can capture the value using a default argument value in the lambda. These are evaluated fully when the function is constructed.

```
for attr in ("size", "pos"):
    self.bind(**{attr: lambda *args, attr=attr: setattr(self.background, attr, self.__getattribute__(attr))})
```